# \usepackage[turkish]{babel} and \includegraphics inconcistency

Tags: graphics, languages, include, babel, books

Here is my document :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

% must-have packages
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % This package will support Turkish chars
% must-have packages

\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

% settings
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% settings

\begin{document}

\framebox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./images/image_3.png}}

\end{document}
```

When I try to build a pdf out of this file I received bunch of errors. here is one of them :

> Missing \endcsname inserted
>   ...graphics[scale=0.5]{./images/image_3.png}}

When I remove the babel package, it runs smoothly. Even when I change the language to another language, it runs as well.

What is happening here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you please include `\usepackage{pgf}` and then try to use `\pgfimage[height=3cm]{./images/image_3}` . I wonder if the active character problem propagates.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believed that this problem had been solved, but it seems not.

Since you can input directly Turkish specific characters as Unicode, you should not need the `=` shortcuts; so

```
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}
```

will cure the problem. In case you really need the shortcuts with `=`, the unique way seems to be to say

```
\shorthandoff{=}
```

before all `\includegraphics` commands and `\shorthandon{=}` again after them.

Comment: The problem is still present as of TeXLive 2016. I really wonder why it has not been fixed.

Comment: @Vesnog I don't know why.

Comment: Yet the problem seems to affect bibliography (biblatex) in **XeTex** and I get errors like:

`Extended mathchar used as mathchar (6300214). \initiate@active@char{:}`


For bibliography


`Package keyval Error: hash=dde4eb9b1037974a732fc2c98a9f94b4 undefined. ^^I\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]`

Comment: What problems did you find using this solution? The manual explains another possibility: “The = shorthand is potentially dangerous. You can deactivate with the babel option `shorthands` or with `\shorthandoff`: `\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}`”.

Comment: @JavierBezos The shorthand *is* dangerous, but if it exists there should be a reason. Besides, setting `shorthands=<whatever>` requires knowing all shorthands to keep and this might get complicated with several active languages. So, no: I don't consider it a solution.

Comment: @egreg The original author added this shorthand to follow a typographical convention in Turkish. Well, definitely I wouldn't add it, but it's a legitimate use of a shorthand, and a documented one, too. And you are right in that `shorthands` requires knowing all shorthands in the document, but that's the point (activate only those you actually know, need and use). Very likely, the default should be 'no shorthands at all', but changing it is not that easy!

Comment: @egreg Is this a problem specific to Turkish? Which package/repo I should report for an issue/bug?

Comment: @MSH This is about `babel`, not `polyglossia`. And, specifically, `babel` for Turkish. Are you sure you linked the right post?

Comment: @MSH I can't understand what you want to point out, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the answers on this question: [\newgeometry doesn't work with Turkish babel package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160385/46172). One answer by @karlkoeller gives an automatic way of switching the shorthand off before `\includegraphics` then on again after it.