# Problem with using scale while using \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, errors, babel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\usepackage[turkish]{babel} and \includegraphics inconcistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32178/usepackageturkishbabel-and-includegraphics-inconcistency)

I previously imported many figures to TEX files and simply use the corresponding parameters without any problems. However, this time I am preparing some slides using beamer and I couldn't figure what's wrong with it. Here is my TEX code related with the problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[turkish]{babel}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Markov Karar Süreçleri}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img/mdp.eps}
%\includegraphics{img/mdp.eps}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code exists with many compile errors. However, when I simply comment out the includegraphics line scale parameters and uncomment the other one, it compiles smoothly.

Any ideas are welcome..

Comment: actually it is..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believed that the problem had been solved, but apparently it hasn't.

The issue is in the fact that the Turkish module for `babel` activates the `=` character as a shorthand.

If you don't need the `=` in text (which is hardly ever needed), you can simply forget about its activation and issue

```
\shorthandoff{=}
```

just after `\begin{document}`.

A different way to solve the problem is to load `xkeyval` (an extension of the `keyval` package loaded by `graphicx`); in this way no `\shorthandoff` is necessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[turkish]{babel}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Markov Karar Süreçleri}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img/mdp.eps}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That solves the problem..

Comment: @OrhanSönmez See edited message for a different solution