# Beamer crashes with babel Turkish package

Tags: beamer, graphics, babel

I just started to learn beamer and noticed that the problem in [\usepackage[turkish]{babel} and \includegraphics inconcistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32178/usepackageturkishbabel-and-includegraphics-inconcistency) question applies for beamer and `\shorthandoff{=}` solution does not work. Has anyone have another solution? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \shorthandoff{=}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{resimler/stmornek2.png}
    \shorthandon{=}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example, please?

Answer (score 3):

It works if you move the commands outside the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{resimler/stmornek2.png}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\shorthandon{=}
\end{document}
```

or if you add the `fragile` option to the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{figure}
    \shorthandoff{=}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{resimler/stmornek2.png}
    \shorthandon{=}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As **egreg** mentions in his comment, you are using the `utf8` option for `inputenc`, so you don't really need the `=` shorthands for the `turkish` module of `babel`, and you can simply deactivate them after `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{resimler/stmornek2.png}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: lets hope that other things in the frame wont be affected, anyway Thank you.

Comment: @AhmetSadıkYorulmaz If you use UTF-8, you won't need the `=` shorthands for Turkish, so you can say `\shorthandoff{=}` after `\begin{document}` and forget about it.

Comment: Gonzalo, @AhmetSadıkYorulmaz: Did anyone tried to use the `[fragile]` option of `frame`? It will handle most verbatim issues, and this seems to be one.

Comment: @MartinScharrer in fact, **egreg** mentioned the use of `fragile` in the chat room, but taking into account his comment (the shorthand will not be needed anyway), I decided not to include this option. I will however do so, since it could be useful for the case in which `utf8` is not used.