# Resizing the image in Uzk-theme

Tags: beamer, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beamer crashes with babel Turkish package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56694/beamer-crashes-with-babel-turkish-package)

I am using Beamer theme for the University of Cologne, named uzk-theme.
I would like to add an image to this theme, however, it doesn't work.
[image]

This is what I like to add.
but it looks like this on the slide. [image]
This is my code.

```
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{image1.png}
    \end{figure}
```

Just help me please, I need it urgently.

This is a MVE

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[turkish, ngerman, english]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{enumerate}

    \usetheme[%
    %wiso,        %% Wiso-Fakultaet
    %jura,        %% Rechtswissenschaftliche Fakultaet
    %medizin,     %% Medizinische Fakultaet
    %philo,       %% Philosophische Fakultaet
    %matnat,      %% Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche Fakultaet
    %human,       %% Humanwissenschaftliche Fakultaet
    %verw,        %% Universitaetsverwaltung
    %nav,         %% Schaltet die Navigationssymbole ein
    %latexfonts,  %% verwendet die latex-beamer-Standardschrift
    ]{UzK}

    \title[Destek Vektör Makineleri Üzerine Bir Çalışma \\ A Study On Support Vector Machines]{ \fontsize{13}{12}\selectfont Destek Vektör Makineleri Üzerine Bir Çalışma \\ (A Study On Support Vector Machines)}

    \author[Arş. Gör. Mustafa Murat ARAT]% {Mustafa Murat ARAT\thanks{\href{mailto:muratarat@hacettepe.edu.tr}{muratarat@hacettepe.edu.tr}}}

    \institute[Destek Vektör Makineleri Üzerine Bir Çalışma]{\textbf{Danışman:} Doç. Dr. Turhan MENTEŞ\thanks{\href{mailto:mentes@hacettepe.edu.tr}{mentes@hacettepe.edu.tr}}\\[12pt]İstatistik Bölümü \\ Hacettepe Üniversitesi\\ 06800\\ Ankara, Türkiye}

    \date{18 Eylül 2012}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[titlepage]
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}


    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Die Fußzeile}
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{image1.png}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

AND this is where you can download the theme. https://github.com/solstice/uzk-theme

Comment: Don't use `figure`, just `\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=.8\textheight,keepaspectratio]{image1}`

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. I got "Missing \endcsname inserted <to be read again> \textwidth 1.57 \end{frame}" error.

Comment: Please add a complete MWE.

Comment: I added a minimal working example.

Comment: Turkish is a dangerous language (in latex). It makes the `=` active. Add `\shorthandoff{=}` before the frame.

Comment: @MuratArat The `figure` environment is useless

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is totally right. I removed my previous comment. it worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: And @egreg yes you are right. The figure environment is useless. Thank you!!