# Extra space within bold text

Tags: spacing, bold

I want to extra space within a bold text. When I use the `\textbf{}` command it removes the extra space I put in it. My code is as follows:

```
\textbf{My bold text\qquad:}
```

Here `\textbf` removes the extra space that I put inside the bold text. It removes the extra space even if I move it out out of the bold part.

```
\textbf{My bold text}\qquad\textbf{:}
```

This is the same when I use italic or underlined text. Extra space I use is removed. This problem only occurs when you use a colon as the last character in the bold part. If I use something else as the last character the space is reserved. But, it is removed if you use a colon as the last character within the bold part.
How can I solve this problem?

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\flushleft
\underline{\textbf{ACIKLAMALAR \quad}:} \\

\end{document}
```

If put something else instead of the colon at the end it works just right. If I put the colon outside the `\underline` it works. But that is not what I want.

Comment: you'll have to provide more details—it works for me!  can you provide a minimal working example: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Sorry for that. As I explained above, the problem only occurs when you use a colon as the last character of the bold part.

Comment: Please post a _complete_ small document that shows the problem. (I would guess that you are using some babel language style that makes `:` active and adjusts the space. What you describe is not standard behaviour and you have not given enough of a clue how to reproduce it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I hope this explanation suffice. Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem of `:` being an active character in the Turkish language for `babel`, and gobbling other bits of the document.
There was a similar problem being discussed [in a similar question here a few years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32178/usepackageturkishbabel-and-includegraphics-inconcistency). Credit to egreg for the answer, which is to add the line

```
\shorthandoff{:}
```

to disable the active character, and just use Unicode to enter Turkish characters. You can add

```
\shorthandon{:}
% some stuff here
\shorthandoff{:}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{:}

\flushleft

\textbf{ALongWord:} \\
\textbf{ALongWord :} \\
\textbf{ALongWord \qquad:} \\
\textbf{ALongWord \qquad\qquad:} \\
\textbf{ALongWord \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad:}

\end{document}
```

Here's the effect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized that I don't need the babel package if I just need to use the Turkish characters. Using utf8 with inputenc does the job. So removing the babel package solves my problem here.