# \newgeometry doesn't work with Turkish babel package

Tags: margins, babel, geometry

`\newgeometry` is a nice feature of `geometry` package. I found out that it doesn't work (together with many other problems) when `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` is also used with many errors stating:

> Missing \endcsname inserted...

This seems to be a bug in Turkish babel which inserts space next to every "=" sign. I found a workaround:

```
\shorthandoff{=}
\newgeometry{top=1cm}
\shorthandon{=}
```

Any better ideas on getting this to work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Same problem as here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32178/27635. It seems that the problem is still unsolved.

Comment: @karlkoeller exactly. Is there an automatic way to do this, i am now having problems with every `\includegraphics` too. I mean automatically issue `\shorthandoff{=}` before `\includegraphics` then  `\shorthandon{=}` after it. I have been searching around with no answers up to now. Should I ask this in a separate question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A solution for `\includegraphics` as you've requested in the above comments.

Add the following lines in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \shorthandon{=}%
  }
\pretocmd{\includegraphics}{\shorthandoff{=}}{}{}
```

We first redefine `\includegraphics` to add `\shorthandon{=}` after it and then, through the `\pretocmd` command from the `etoolbox` package, we prefix `\includegraphics` with `\shorthandoff{=}`.

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \shorthandon{=}%
  }
\pretocmd{\includegraphics}{\shorthandoff{=}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason that you don’t add `\shorthandoff` directly in the redefinition?

Comment: @Tobi, because it doesn't work.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn’t work?

Comment: Thanks, and I must say I am mystified about things that mystically don't work in LaTeX

Comment: @Tobi: Catcodes cannot be changed after reading and tokenizing. If the definition text of `\includegraphics` is executed, then it has already seen and tokenized its arguments. Changing the catcodes with `\shorthandoff{=}` comes too late.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 10):

`\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` makes `=` active. That disturbs key value parser, because they usually assume that the syntax characters `=` and `,` have the usual catcode (other=12). The official way is indeed using

```
\shorthandoff{=}
% stuff that does not expect an active `=', e.g.
\newgeometry{top=1cm}
\shorthandon{=}
```

### Package `keyval`: `\kvsetkeys`

A more comfortable way is provided by package `kvsetkeys`. Its key value parser was written with `turkish.ldf` in mind. Thus it supports active syntax characters in key value lists. The package defines `\kvsetkeys`, which can now be
used as direct replacement for `\setkeys` of package `keyval`:

```
\usepackage{keyval,kvsetkeys}
\let\setkeys\kvsetkeys
```

### Package `xkeyval`

The package directly redefines and extends `\setkeys`:

```
\usepackage{xkeyval}
```

hen active equal signs are supported in key value lists that are processed by `\setkeys`.

### Compatibility

Package `xkeyval` also changes more things, like the parsing of package and class options, even for packages that do not use or know `xkeyval`.
Therefore I consider the solution with `kvsetkeys` less intrusive.

However, both solutions can easily cooperate, even if `xkeyval` might be loaded by the class or other packages.
The trick is using the first method as early as possible:

```
\RequirePackage{keyval,kvsetkeys}
\let\setkeys\kvsetkeys

% classes and packages that might load xkeyval
\documentclass{...}

% packages in any order, e.g. 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% then the following works without `\shorthandoff{=}`:
\newgeometry{top=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}
```

Then active equal signs are supported by package `kvsetkeys` as default or by `xkeyval` for the case that it is loaded later.

Comment: But the following don't work this time:
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
    \draw [thick,red!50!black]
    ([shift={(+10mm,-10mm)}]current page.north west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(-10mm,+10mm)}]current page.south east) 
    ;
}%

Comment: @Sinan: `tikz` has its own key value parser, package `pgfkeys` and contains syntax stuff that include the equals sign outside of key value pairs. Thus "fixing" `\setkeys` will not help and you need `\shorthandoff{=}`.

Answer (score 7):

With `babel` 3.9 (if you are not using it, upgrade, because it fixes tons of bugs):

```
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}
```

or if you want `:` and `!`:

```
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
```

The Turkish style has been upgrade recently, too. The new manual explains how to deal with the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\shorthandon{=}`. With following code, it seems there is no problem.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}
\newgeometry{top=1cm}
\section{ğüşiöç}
\lipsum[1]
\includegraphics[scale=1]{}
\newgeometry{top=10cm}
\section{ĞÜŞİÖÇ}
\lipsum[2]
\includegraphics[scale=1]{}
\end{document}
```