# The scale option of \includegraphics does not work after changing the document class

Tags: graphics, document-classes, scaling

After .cls file changes, 
`\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img/GoalHierarchyMetaModel.png}` command gives the following error.

```
! Package keyval Error: scale=0.5 undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.6 ...[scale=0.5]{img/GoalHierarchyMetaModel.png}
```

[MWE](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9kruQqpAmMgWWpDcV9qMzk3QUE&usp=sharing) can be accessed from google drive in [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9kruQqpAmMgWWpDcV9qMzk3QUE&usp=sharing).

`main_e.tex` is the working one, `main_m.tex` outputs error above. Only difference between those files is `documentclass`.

- `main_e.tex` uses  `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`
- `main_m.tex` uses `\documentclass[chaparabic,ceng,phd,12pt,oneandhalf]{metu}`

Comment: Let me guess: you have `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`.

Comment: Possibly the first class loads `graphicx` while the second loads `graphics`. I recommend you explicitly load `graphicx` if you want to include image files.

Comment: If you're using `babel` for Turkish, look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32178/usepackageturkishbabel-and-includegraphics-inconcistency

Comment: @NicolaTalbot nah you wouldn't get a keyval error from graphics: something has made `=` not catcode 12.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, weird. Next thing you know some package will make square brackets active.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: What itself is marked as duplicate of [\usepackage\[turkish\]{babel} and \includegraphics inconcistency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32178).

Comment: @Speravir: But the latter does not contain the alternative solution of egreg via `xkeyval`. Thus some merging should be done.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Or even better: [`\newgeometry` doesn't work with Turkish babel package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160385/newgeometry-doesnt-work-with-turkish-babel-package), because it does contain much more solution ways.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Ah, but now both questions will appear as original to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As egreg guessed your class has `\RequirePackage[english,turkish]{babel}` which apparently redefines `=` you need to locally set it back:

```
{\shorthandoff=%
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img/GoalHierarchyMetaModel.png}}
```