# Interaction between babel [turkish] option and rotating package

Tags: errors, babel, rotating, amssymb

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\olok}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{135}{$\twoheadrightarrow$}}
\olok
\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

But, It takes `Missing \endcsname inserted` when I added `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`.

I didn't find about this question. Does anyone know how to fix it?

(Perhaps about`\shorthandoff{}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `\olok` within the document *preamble*, not inside the document where you'll have other content-related information:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

% Document-related definitions
\newcommand{\olok}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{135}{$\twoheadrightarrow$}}

\begin{document}
\olok
\end{document}
```

The above suggestion is a minor work-around.

The problem is related to the use of `=` which is made active under `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`. As such, `origin=c` is not interpreted in the way one would expect a key=value input should be. For general applications, you can momentarily switch off the "active-ness" of `=` using

```
\shorthandoff{=}% Make = not active any more
\rotatebox[origin=c]{135}{$\twoheadrightarrow$}
\shorthandon{=}% Make = active again
```

Comment: Question [Closed]. I'm sorry. I'm very tired. I couldn't think.

Comment: This is not actually an answer to the question, although it is kind of a workaround.  If you simply put `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\twoheadrightarrow$}` into the document and load the `[turkish]` option, the document fails.  So there's more to the problem than this.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I see... this has to do (it seems) with an improper interpretation of `=`.

Comment: It usually needs `\shorthandoff{=}`. I think it is a dupe of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160385/newgeometry-doesnt-work-with-turkish-babel-package

Comment: @percusse: Correct...