# Error when including .tex file created with XCircuit in Latex mode

Tags: graphics, scaling, eps

I've recently created an eps figure using XCircuit. Labels of the components written in "LaTeX Mode" to have the default LaTeX font. When i try to compile my .tex file i get the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty)
No file ELEC331_mono.aux.
[1] (../fig/exp1_bridge2.tex

! Package keyval Error: scale=1 undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16    }
          % close 'scalebox'
?
```

Here is my main .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[turkish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\graphicspath{{../fig/}}
\title{\textbf{ELEC 331 - Electronic Circuits 2} \\ Laboratory Manuals}
\author{Author}


\begin{document}

\maketitle 
\input{../fig/exp1_bridge2.tex}

\end{document}
```

And here is the .tex file created by XCircuit:

```
% XCircuit output "ELEC331_LAB/fig/exp1_bridge2.tex" for LaTeX input from ELEC331_LAB/fig/exp1_bridge2.eps
\def\putbox#1#2#3#4{\makebox[0in][l]{\makebox[#1][l]{}\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{\raisebox{#2}[0in][0in]{\scalebox{#3}{#4}}}}}
\def\rightbox#1{\makebox[0in][r]{#1}}
\def\centbox#1{\makebox[0in]{#1}}
\def\topbox#1{\raisebox{-0.60\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{#1}}
\def\midbox#1{\raisebox{-0.20\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{#1}}
   \scalebox{1}{
   \normalsize
   \parbox{4.42188in}{
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{exp1_bridge2}\\
   % translate x=672 y=278 scale 0.38
   \putbox{3.97in}{1.25in}{1.20}{vout(t)}%
   \putbox{0.06in}{1.34in}{1.20}{vin(t)}%
   \putbox{2.22in}{1.92in}{1.20}{D1}%
   } % close 'parbox'
   } % close 'scalebox'
   \vspace{-\baselineskip} % this is not necessary, but looks better
```

Any advices?

Comment: Don't load `epsfig`. Period.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: For volunteers. The following MWE shows the same issue: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[turkish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document} 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{exp1_bridge2}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks LaRiFaRi, I'll keep that in mind. Werner, i tried your suggestion. It didn't help. And also found this in XCircuit Manual: "Because the XCircuit .tex output uses the epsfig command, it is necessary for the LaTeX document to include the epsfig package in its setup section."

Comment: The problem is with `turkish` language that makes the character `=` active. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160385/27635 for a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is with turkish language that makes the character = active. See tex.stackexchange.com/q/160385/27635 for a workaround

Thanks karlkoeller, it was related with turkish language. As you suggested in your other comments, adding `\shorthandoff{=}` and `\shorthandon{=}` before and after `\includegraphics` command solved the problem.