# Includegraphics scaling and babel in Hebrew

Tags: graphics, babel, hebrew

I have a similar problem to this question:

[\usepackage[turkish]{babel} and \includegraphics inconcistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32178/usepackageturkishbabel-and-includegraphics-inconcistency)

But I am trying to do the same in hebrew. I get an error, and the solution offered in that question - setting \shorthandoff{=}
doesn't seem to work with hebrew babel.

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{culmus}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\R{

 שלום

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}

שלום

}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks! I should add that replacing the include graphics line with: \includegraphics{test}  (i.e, without the scaling) the result does compile.

Comment: I cannot run the example: Package `culmus` is not in TeX Live and the found [`culmus.sty`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ivritex/culmus-latex/ci/master/tree/culmus.sty) seems to be wrong, because it requires `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` *before* `\usepackage{culmus}` because of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. Also, TeX Live seems to miss the Hebrew fonts (automatic TFM generation fails).

Comment: `hebrew.ldf` does not seem to use `=` as shorthand, thus the cause seems different to `turkish.ldf`. If it is a category code problem, then the command can be put into a macro, e.g.: `\newcommand*{\TestImage}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}}\documentclass[12pt]{article}...\begin{document}...\R{...\TestImage...}...\end{document}`. If this fixes the issue, then the cause can be a category problem, and the test also provides a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Putting it into a macro did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Then it does not seem to be related to the category code problem of `=` in `turkish.ldf`. Are there any warnings or errors? Which TeX compiler (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`) is used? Is package `culmus` necessary for the problem (where can it be downloaded)?

Comment: culmus is not nessecery, it just contains the font I am using (I think). I am using pdflatex, and the error I get is: pdfTex warning: pdflatex.exe: \pdfrestore missing \pdfsafe
!pdfTex error: pdflatex.exe: 1 unmatched \pdfsave after page shipout

Comment: Then left-to-right writing mode should be used with `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short summary from the comments:

- It is not a category code problem of `=`, because the equals sign is not a shorthand of `hebrew.ldf`.
- The TeX compiler `pdflatex` is used.
- The warning and error:

  ```
  pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: \pdfrestore: missing \pdfsave
  !pdfTeX error: pdflatex: 1 unmatched \pdfsave after page shipout
  ```

The order of `\pdfsave` and `\pdfrestore` is important. Obviously, the order get messed up by right-to-left-writing mode. This can be fixed by using left-to-right for `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\R{
  \L{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}
}
\end{document}
```